# how to modify the legend and the background in matplotlib?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

Consider the small example below. Note, I am interested in sticking (as much as possible) to the `.plot()` method in Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

idx = pd.date_range('2020-02-03', freq = 'T', periods = 29)
df = pd.DataFrame({'value1' : np.random.randn(len(idx)),
                   'value2' : 100*np.random.randn(len(idx))})
df.index = idx

df.plot(y = ['value1', 'value2'], secondary_y = 'value2')
```

[image]

I would like to do two simple things.

1. How can I increase the size of the text in the legend? Using `.legend(fontsize = 20)` will mysteriously only show one label.
2. How can I shade (say, in yellow) the background in the chart between `00:10` and `00:15`?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think you have direct access to the secondary axis/legend label with `df.plot`. Maybe consider plot them manually.

Comment: interesting, thanks. Do you mind submitting your idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually plot like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(y = 'value1', ax=ax)
# cache the legend
hs, ls = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()

# remove this legend
ax.legend().remove()

# a twinx instance
ax1 = ax.twinx()

# plot `value2` on twinx
df.plot(y='value2', ax=ax1, color='C1')

# cache the legend handles/labels
h1s, l1s = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()

# plot the legend
ax1.legend(hs+h1s, ls+[x+ ' (right)' for x in l1s], fontsize=20)

# get the y limits
ymin,ymax = ax1.get_ylim()

# fill_between for background
ax1.fill_between(pd.to_datetime(['2020-02-03 00:00','2020-02-03 00:15']),
                 [ymin,ymin], [ymax,ymax], color='y', alpha=0.4)

# re-enforce the y limits
ax1.set_ylim(ymin, ymax)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: really nice! thanks! may I ask you how can I add a vertical 'red' line at `00:20`?

Comment: `ax1.axvline(pd.Timestamp('2020-02-03 00:20'), ymin, ymax, color='r')` before `ax1.set_ylim`.

Comment: btw why do you need the python comprehension list here `ax1.legend(hs+h1s, ls+[x+ ' (right)' for x in l1s], fontsize=20)`